# Download sequences of isoforms

Tags: rna-seq, phylogenetics, sequence-analysis, phylogeny, isoform

I want to collect all isoforms of all genes (Fasta/Fastq file of nucleotide and protein sequences) Arabidopsis Col-0. I am wondering if there is a straightforward way to download the file from any database.

I am new to sequence analysis, so I apologize if asking a very basic question.

Comment: Do you want a single gene? Look at Uniprot then

Comment: IMO you are into alternate splicing sites, more proteomics and RNAseq than genomics.

Answer (score 1):

Col-0 is, to my knowledge, the standard reference Arabidopsis thaliana ecotype, so the easiest way to get the sequences for all genes is to just download them from Ensembl. The nucleotide sequences are [available here](ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/release-46/plants/fasta/arabidopsis_thaliana/cdna/) and the protein sequences [here](ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/release-46/plants/fasta/arabidopsis_thaliana/pep/).

Answer (score 0):

For RefSeq data, go to [NCBI homepage](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) and search for `Arabidopsis Col-0 genome`. Click on the 'Get Data' button in the result box and you will be directed to the [NCBI Datasets](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/datasets/genomes/?acc=GCF_000001735.4) portal with the latest RefSeq assembly selected. Click on the blue 'Download' button, uncheck the genome and GFF3 files from list, check transcript and protein FASTA files from the list and download data.